# Why is post title not showing up?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So here it is: [image]
For some reason this is not showing the title for my post.
However when I press show option and it goes to post's page you can see al the detail.

```
  _form.html.erb
  <%= form_with(model: post, local: true) do |form| %>
  <% if post.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(post.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this post from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% post.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :date %>
    <%= form.datetime_select :date, id: :post_date %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :name %>
    <%= form.text_area :name, id: :post_name %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :user_id %>
    <%= form.number_field :user_id, id: :post_user_id, value: current_user.id %>

  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :description %>
    <%= form.text_area :description, id: :post_description %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= form.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**#show.html.erb**

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<p>
  <strong>Date:</strong>
  <%= @post.date %>
</p>

<p>
    <strong>Name:</strong>
    <%= @post.name %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>User:</strong>
  <%= @post.user_id %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Description:</strong>
  <%= @post.description %>
</p>

<% if current_user == @post.user %>
 <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_post_path(@post) %> |
<%end%>
 <%= link_to 'Back', posts_path %>




<h1>Editing Post</h1>

<%= render 'form', post: @post %>

<%= link_to 'Show', @post %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', posts_path %>
```

edit.html.erb

```
<%= render 'form', post: @post %>

<%= link_to 'Show', @post %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', posts_path %>
```

I've tried changing it `<%= form.text_area :name, id: :post_name %>`
to string_area :name and also string_field but none of it is working.
In fact when I change it to the last 2, I get a method error if I go on the edit page. I'm still fairly new to rails and to ruby so I would greatly appreciate some help. I did try to google however and was unsuccessful, I guess I didn't know what to search for or maybe I worded it wrong.

Comment: Its not clear that what you want, can edit question & specifically ask that what you want?

Comment: I just want the title of the post to show up on my posts page.

Comment: What view is this image? show? Index?

Comment: `form.text_field` is used to create a `<input type="text" ...>`. Are you sure you whitelisted the name attribute in your controller?

Comment: kindly share code of PostsController

Comment: Can you share your schema file?

Comment: You are showing us the code for your form and for your `show` action but I think you are asking why it doesn't show in the `index` action. Please show `posts_controller.rb` file and `index.html.erb`

Comment: Thanks for all the help guys, I figured it out. It wasn't in my index.html.erb